# while (getchar != '\n'); alternative to clear the buffer

Tags: c, input

I read that `getchar()` returns that char it reads, so I'm wondering if this can be alternative for `while (getchar() != '\n');` to clear the buffer. I haven't see any similar codes yet using this technique to clear the buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char clearBuffer(void) {
    char cChar;
    scanf("%c", &cChar);
    return cChar;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    do {
        printf("Enter N: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        while (clearBuffer() != '\n');
        printf("N is %d\n", n);
    } while (n != 0);
}
```

Comment: Did it work? Did you measure its performance?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, it seems to work fine. It doesnt result in an infinite loop when i try to enter a character

Comment: `clearBuffer()` might invoke undefined behaviour in the case of detecting end-of-file.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that `getchar()` returns that char it reads,

Detail: `int getchar(void);` returns an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  Typically 257 different values, so returning a `char` would be insufficient.

> I'm wondering if this can be alternative for `while(getchar() != '\n');` to clear the buffer.

`while (clearBuffer() != '\n');` is *undefined behavior* (UB)  when end-of-file is encountered. `cChar` in `scanf("%c", &cChar);` is not assigned a value, yet returned.  [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226798/while-getchar-n-alternative-to-clear-the-buffer/59228379#comment104667543_59226798)

`while (getchar() != '\n');` is an infinite loop when end-of-file is encountered.

Neither is a robust solution.

---

A simply alternative:

```
// Read and dispose of data from stdin until \n or EOF encountered
// Return \n or EOF
int clearBuffer1(void) {
  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ;
  }
  return ch;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why the return type is int rather than char?

Comment: @Janjan Function only returns 1 of 2 values: `EOF, '\n'`.  `EOF` is negative in the `int` range.  `'\n'` is positive in the `unsigned char` range. `char` as _signed_ `char` or _unsigned_ `char` does not certainly encode both values.  `int` does.

Comment: @Janjan No.  If `char` is _unsigned_, it cannot encode `EOF`.  If `char` is _signed_, `'\n'`  may be more than `CHAR_MAX`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but what about reading the whole line and then convert to `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_line();

int main(void) {
    char *n;
    int num;
    do {
        printf("Enter N: ");
        n = get_line();
        num = atoi(n);
        printf("N is %d\n", num);
    } while (num != 0);
    free(n);
}

char *get_line()
    char *n = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);  // no int has more than 11 chars
    int c;
    for (int i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i) {
        // check if i < 11 or reallocate memory to read more chars
        n[i] = c;
    }
    n[11] = '\0';  // if memory reallocated then 11 is not the right value
    return n;
}
```

There's no error checking to keep things simple.

Comment: Reading the whole line is a good alternative although this `get_line()` has weaknesses.  1. It does not return a _string_ (no \0) 2 `INT_MIN` needs a buffer of at least 12.  3) User input may exceed expectations 4) no handling of `EOF`. 5) `atoi()` is UB on overflow. .....

Comment: 1- Yes, I know there are some problems with it, but I missed `\0`
2- for signed numbers ?
3 & 5- Yes, this is the kind of error checking I skipped.
4- Although it was mentioned in the comments and I intended to handle it, I forgot, but I fixed 1 & 2 & 4 now.

Comment: Good improvement.  Note "no int has more than 11 digits" is more like "no int has more than 11 characters" as in "-‭2147483648‬".  `n[11] = '\0';` is curious.  `n[i] = '\0';` makes more sense to append the _null character_ after the last read character.  `c != EOF` is a problem when `char` is unsigned as it is never true.  Better to use `int c;`.

Comment: Oh, I meant chars.

I made it `n[11] = '\0'` because it seems that the shell appends a `'\0'` after I press enter, so I added it at the end in case of overflows.

Thanks for that note, I have changed it now.